# Asus vivobook s430un compatitiblity

Tags: asus

Are asus vivobook s430un compatible with ubuntu,I am thinking of switching to this new one,I am new in here.

Comment: Why don't you try it on your actual hardware?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install  Asking for recommendations on hardware is off-topic here sorry (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I haven't buy it yet, I'm just asking if it is compatible or not,but if there is no exact answer then I will try it I guess